# Scrapy xpath href ou span dentro da div

Tags: python, scrapy

Olá, estou tentando fazer uma raspagem onde tenho que pegar um link e um texto porém estou com dificuldades por causa das variações da página.
Tenho 3 variações possíveis:

1.

```
<div>
<strong>
    <span style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">
        <a href="www...com.br" target="_blank">Edição</a>&nbsp;-&nbsp;
    </span>
</strong>
<span style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">01/12/2017
</span>
</div>
```

2.

```
<div>
<span style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">
    <a href="www...com.br">
        <strong>Edição</strong>
    </a>&nbsp;- 04/12/2017
</span>
</div>
```

3.

```
<div>
    <a href="www...com.br">
        <strong>Edição</strong>
    </a>&nbsp;- 05/12/2017
</div>
```

Preciso pegar o link dentro do href e a data. O link consigo pegar com

```
response.xpath('//a[contains(@href,"www...com.br")]')
```

Não estou conseguindo pegar a data.
Estou tentando achar uma solução onde eu consiga pegar o link e a data dentro dessas variações de codigo.

Desde já obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Você pode postar qual é a página que você está tentando parsear?

Comment: Página:http://www.uberlandia.mg.gov.br/?pagina=Conteudo&id=3077

Answer (score 1):

Pode fazer dessa forma abaixo, to preferindo usar o BeautifulSoup é bem mais simples e resolve perfeitamente.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import scrapy

class MgUberlandia(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'mg_uberlandia'
    start_urls = ['http://www.uberlandia.mg.gov.br/?pagina=Conteudo&id=3077']

    def parse(self, response):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.body_as_unicode())
        a = soup.find_all('a')

        for link in a:
            print(link.get('href'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Baseado no teu exemplo, podemos ver que existem dois padrões:

**Datas dentro do `span` (caso 1 e 2):**

```
response.xpath('//div/span/text()').extract()
```

Output:

```
['01/12/2017\n        ', '\n            ', '\xa0- 04/12/2017\n        ']
```

**Datas soltas na `div` (caso 3):**

```
response.xpath('//div/text()').extract()
```

Output:

```
'\n        ', '\n        ', '\n    ', '\n        ', '\n    ', '\n        ', '\xa0- 05/12/2017\n    ']
```

Uma estratégia para resolver o problema seria:

1) Checa se a primeira opção encontra;

2) Se não encontrar na primeira, tenta a segunda.

Sendo que para as duas tu teria que limpar os dados: remover os `\n`, talvez usar regex pra encontrar o padrão DD/MM/YYYY etc.

Pra chegar a essas conclusões eu criei uma página HTML apenas com o exemplo que você colou aqui. Os caminhos podem mudar de acordo com a página.